# grid layout, how to make the last item take place the rest space of row

Tags: css

I want to implement this style where the last item can always take place the rest space of a row, so the layout can be a square without any gap
[image]

Is there anyway to implement this using ONLY css?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Alright.. I know how to implement this usign FLEX box, I wonder is it possible to do this using GRID layout , like `grid-column-end: auto / -1`, I tried but not work. Here the demo: https://jsfiddle.net/justforuse/03txLpzq/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can use flexbox for this - just add flex-grow to the last-child and it will take the rest of the row

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-bottom:30px;
}

.item {
  flex-basis:33.333333%;
  border:1px solid black;
}


.item:last-child {
  flex-grow:1
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">1</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">1</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">1</div>
</div>
```

Comment: don't know you just asked if it was possible, yes it is using flex.  If you only wanted grid answers, perhaps you should have stated that in the question